# when a process is killed is this information recorded anywhere?

Tags: linux, process, kill

### Question:

- When a process is killed, is this information recorded anywhere (i.e., in kernel), such as syslog (or can be configured to be recorded syslog.conf)
- Is the information of the killer's PID, time and date when killed and reason

**update -** you have all giving me some insight, thank you very much|

Comment: This might be better asked on superuser, if you're mostly curious about existing solutions.

Comment: @Josh: it might be programming related, if Aaron is interested in how to implement kill-logging. If he just wants to know if it's possible with existing technologies, then you're right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your Linux kernel is compiled with the process accounting (`CONFIG_BSD_PROCESS_ACT`) option enabled, you can start recording process accounting info using the `accton(8)` command and use `sa(8)` to access the recorded info.  The recorded information includes the 32 bit exit code which includes the signal number.

(This stuff is not widely known / used these days, but I still remember it from the days of 4.x Bsd on VAXes ...)

Answer (score 4):

**Amended:**
In short, the OS kernel does not care if the process is killed. That is dependant on whether the process logs anything. All the kernel cares about at this stage is reclaiming memory. But read on, on how to catch it and log it...

As per **caf** and **Stephen C**'s mention on their comments...

1. If you are running BSD accounting daemon module in the kernel, everything gets logged. Thanks to Stephen C for pointing this out! I did not realize that functionality as I have this switched off/disabled.
2. In my hindsight, as per caf's comment - the two signals that cannot be caught are *SIGKILL* and *SIGSTOP*, and also the fact that I mentioned `atexit`, and I described in the code, that should have been `exit(0);`..ooops Thanks caf!

*Original*

The best way to catch the kill signal is you need to use a signal handler to handle a few signals <strike>, not just `SIGKILL` on its own will suffice,</strike> `SIGABRT` (abort), `SIGQUIT` (terminal program quit), <strike>`SIGSTOP`</strike> and `SIGHUP` (hangup). Those signals together is what would catch the command `kill` on the command line. The signal handler can then log the information stored in `/var/log/messages` (environment dependant or Linux distribution dependant). For further reference, see [here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/signal.h.html).

Also, see [here](http://www.aquaphoenix.com/ref/gnu_c_library/libc_348.html) for an example of how to use a signal handler using the `sigaction` function.

Also it would be a good idea to adopt the usage of `atexit` function, then when the code **exit**s at runtime, the runtime will execute the last function before returning back to the command line. Reference for `atexit` is [here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/atexit.html).

When the C function `exit` is used, and executed, the `atexit` function will execute the function pointer where applied as in the example below. - Thanks **caf** for this!

An example usage of `atexit` as shown:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
   atexit(myexitfunc); /* Beginning, immediately right after declaration(s) */
    /* Rest of code */
   return 0;
   exit(0);
}

int myexitfunc(void){
   fprintf(stdout, "Goodbye cruel world...\n");
}
```

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Two signals *cannot* be caught - `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP`.  Functions registered with `atexit` are only run if the process exits through calling `exit` or returning from `main`.

Comment: False -- the kernel DOES care if you have the BSD process accounting option enabled in your kernel.

Comment: @caf: I will amend the edit accordingly and thanks for the quick heads up/reminder!

Comment: @Stephen C: I will amend the edit accordingly! It just shows there's some things under Linux that I never bother with... :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any logging of signals sent to processes, unless the OOM killer is doing it.

Comment: @retracile - read up on `sa`, `acct` and `acton` in the Linux manual pages.

Comment: ...better-suited as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `sudo`, it will be logged. Other than that, the killed process can log some information (unless it's being terminated with extreme prejudice). You could even hack the kernel to log signals.

As for recording the reason a process was killed, I've yet to see a psychic program.

Kernel hacking is not for the weak of heart, but hella fun. You'd need to patch the signal dispatch routines to log information using [printk(9)](http://www.digipedia.pl/man/doc/view/printk.9.html) when [kill(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/kill), [sigsend(2)](http://www.phy.ohiou.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi.sol?sigsend+2) or the like is called. Read "[The Linux Signals Handling Model](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3985)" for more information on how signals are handled.

Comment: 1 - where can the 'killed' process log information? syslog?
2 - how can the kernel be 'hacked' to log signals?
thanks...

Comment: Well, that's the issue isn't it. If it's killed it can't very well write to anything so the kernel has to be the one to interpret the signal. But kill is pretty normal so the kernel doesn't actually care that something was killed so you would have to plug in a module to tell it to catch the signal and care. There are actually C wrapper programs that do this though so if you do I'd definitely suggest posting on superuser

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing your own program you can catch the kill signal and write to a logfile before actually dying. This doesn't work with kill -9 though, just the normal kill.

You can see some details over [thisaway](http://tille.garrels.be/training/bash/ch12.html).

Answer (score 1):

If the process is getting it via `kill(2),` then unless the process is already logging the only external trace would be a kernel mod. It's pretty simple; just do a `printk()`, it's like `printf().`   Find the output in `dmesg`.

If the process is getting it via `/bin/kill`, then it would be a relatively easy matter to install a wrapper executable that did logging. But this (signal delivery via `/bin/kill`) is unlikely because kill is also a bash built-in.

Comment: The `*printf` family might be problematic. The Linux kernel offers `printk` (http://www.linuxgrill.com/anonymous/fire/netfilter/kernel-hacking-HOWTO-4.html) as one alternative. There's also syslog (http://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog)

Comment: Scratch `syslog`; it's not safe to call from a kernel context.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, if a process is killed with a signal is announced by the kernel to the parent process via de **wait(2)** system call.  The value returned by this call is the exit status of the child (the lower byte) and some signal related info in the upper byte in case this process has been killed.  See **wait(2)** for more information.